# FPS drops down when using iAd Banners

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, iad, adbannerview

as you can read in the subject, the fps of my game drops down only if I use iAd Banners. By using AdMob Banners, everything is fine...
Is that normal or can I do anything against it.

I initialize the BannerView as usual:

```
self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, screenWidth, 50)];
self.bannerView.delegate = self;
self.bannerView.hidden = true;
[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried running with Instruments to see what's taking up processing time?

Comment: bad iad performance has been reported numerous times before with no accepted answer

Comment: did u test with simulator or real iDevice?

Comment: real iDevice! I removed iAd Banners during the actual game and replaced them with AdMob Banners, so that the fps stays best. In the menu I use both banners...